# A doubt regarding the delta complex structure for a circle

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently self-learning algebraic topology from Hatcher. In page 106, Hatcher computes $H_{n}^{\Delta}(S^1)$. To do this, he says "let $X = S^1$ with one vertex and one edge". The diagram given in the book is clear but I'm not able to see how this is a $\Delta$-complex for a circle. Don't you need 2 1-simplexes, with their endpoints indentified to get a $\Delta$-complex for a circle? In this case you end up with 2 edges and 2 vertices. I apologize in advance if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition that Hatcher uses for $\Delta$-complexes is sufficiently flexible to allow for this. The point is that if $\sigma_\alpha$ is a map of an $n$-simplex with a face $K$, the definition demands that $\sigma|_{K}$ is the same as a characteristic map $\sigma_\beta$ for *some* $n-1$-simplex. In particular, the maps for different faces need not be distinct (this is a difference between $\Delta$ and simplicial complexes). So we are allowed to have both edges of a $1$-simplex be mapped to the same point (and get a representation of $S^1$ as $[0,1]/(0 \sim 1)$).